# Speech Recongnition Using OpenVINO

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, openvino

I want to implement a python project in which the input will be a .mp4 file and the output will be the transcript or subtitle of the video. The constraint is to use OpenVINO. How can I do that?

Comment: This may be useful: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_inference_engine_samples_speech_sample_README.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mp4 is a container. I believe the current OpenVINO speech demo/samples use wav files as that is what the model is trained for.

If you can convert your mp3 or audio from the mp4 container using a tool to convert it to the wav format, that may work.

[speech rec demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5DKG.png)